# Can I send a View to another Activity?

Tags: android, xml

my question is: If for example I have a **RelativeLayout** in **Activity1**, can I send that **RelativeLayout** to **Activity2**?

In my app I have 3 different **RelativeLayout** in **Activity1**, and if the user Clicked on one of those **RelativeLayout** I would to send it to my next activity. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Why do you wanna do this?

Comment: @Shaishav I am giving the user 3 examples of layout he can use for something... And than I am going to the 'show' activity of that suggestion, where he can edit text, image, those things.... Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment it appears you need to load a different layout based on user's selection from previous screen. This problem can be tackled in several ways. One of them is to pass the user preference from `Activity1` to `Activity2`. To do this, in `Activity1`:

```
int choice = 0; // assuming user made choice 0
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("choice", choice); 
startActivity(choice);
```

Now, you can read the second value in `Activity2` and accordingly load your layout (i.e. different view) as (within `onCreate()`):

```
int choice = getIntent().getIntExtra("choice", 0); // default choice 0

switch(choice) {
    case 0:
        setContentView(R.layout.layout0);
        break;

    case 1:
        setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
        break;

    default:
        setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
}
```

Thus, based on user's choice you can choose a different layout and write you business logic accordingly thereafter.

Another option you have for your use case is that you define different activities for each of your layouts and then call `startActivity()` to appropriate activity. This will separate out the business logic of handling the different layouts and may therefore be easy to maintain.

You can also go the fragment way but, ultimately it would also employ one of the above methods. Note that the method you choose highly depends on your use-case and therefore I cannot make that decision for you.

Comment: Thanks @Shaishav, I think that's the closest answer for what I need! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that since each `Activity` has its own layout.

What you can do instead is send the data needed to setup your second `Activity`'s `RelativeLayout` so that it looks like the one in your first `Activity` via `Intent` extras.

Comment: Thanks @npace, the problem is that the Avticvity layout would change depending on each item the user selected. If I used fragments would that make sense? And than just store each fragment the user wants, so I can keep using that fragment on the next activities?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just give you an idea , you can send data from the first activity to the second using **Intents** , however you can create a layout dynamically using data received by the second Activity and adding all the parameters you need. 
*I hope it will help you*